# ListView in Fragment is not shown when using ActionBar with Tabs in Android 4

Tags: android, listview, tabs, android-actionbar, fragment

I created an activity with ActionBar and tabs using the Eclipse wizard. I want to show ListViews inside my three tabs but if they are not shown when I run my app.

The code for the activity with the Tabs:

```
public class CreateProjectManually extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
     * sections. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will
     * keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it may be best
     * to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_project_manually);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        // set the app icon as an action to go home
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        //enable tabs in actionbar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab.
        // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
        // Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
            // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // listener for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Actionbar
     * */ 
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_save:
            //TODO Speichern implementieren
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Speichern",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            break;
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProjectList.class);
            intent.putExtra("Uniqid","From_CreateProjectManually_Activity");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;    
        default:
            break;
        }
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_create_project_manually, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return getString(R.string.building).toUpperCase();
                case 1: return getString(R.string.room).toUpperCase();
                case 2: return getString(R.string.devices).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviews, container, false);

        }
    }

}
```

And the XML-file for the layout with the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="259dp" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The TextView is shown but the ListView not. What is the problem?

Comment: There is no problem with your code, your list view is empty. you must  set and adapter to your list view on the Fragment "DummySectionFragment".

Comment: Of course, now it is shown. Thanks!

Comment: @AnisBENNSIR  I have same problem butlistview is not showing records. listview is not empty i have set simple array adapter with values still it is not working. my code is similar to above snippet just i use fragment as container for tab instead of activity and add two more tabs for swipe event.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create your adapter for the list view that yo have with it's own custom row and find it's id in the onCreateView method based on on the root view like this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar_dummy,
                container, false);
        /*TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) + "HOLA");*/
        //getFavorito(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        //asyncFavorite().execute(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Your own list);
        loadingLista = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadingLista);
        int mes = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        new asyncFavorite().execute(Integer.toString(mes));
        Log.i("mfb", "puse el-----------------" + Integer.toString(mes));

        return rootView;
    }
```

after this you have to create a method to inflate your list, create an array list of your object that contains all the elements of the list and use it to inflate all the rows:

```
m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
            //JSONObject data = new JSONObject(Fetcher.getMonthBirthday(FBAccount, params[0]));
            //resData = data.getJSONArray("data");


            //Log.i("mfb", "RESDATA::::::::::" + resData + "////////////////////" +Index.userID);

            JSONObject objeto = null;

            String nombre = "";
            String cumpliendo = "";
            String mes = "";
            String dia = "";
            String uuid = "";

            String favorite = "";
            String ownerID = "";

            int mesNumero = 0;

            String[] cumple = null;
            String pasoMes = "";

            for(int i = 0; i<resData.length(); i++){
                objeto = resData.getJSONObject(i);
                nombre = objeto.getString("name");
                cumpliendo = objeto.getString("edad");

                cumple = objeto.getString("birthday").split("-");

                dia = cumple[2];
                pasoMes = cumple[1];
                mesNumero = Integer.parseInt(pasoMes);

                //mes = getMes(mesNumero);

                uuid = objeto.getString("uuid");

                favorite = "1";
                ownerID = objeto.getString("user_id");

                m_orders.add(i, new Order(""+nombre, ""+cumpliendo, ""+mes, ""+dia, "" + uuid, ""+favorite, ""+ownerID, "" + FBAccount));                       

                //Log.i("mfb", "HH " + nombre);

            }
```

the you have to set the adapter to your list

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {                   
                        Log.v("mfb", " Runnable "+m_orders.size());
                        adapterOrder = new orderItemAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_orders);
                        lista.setAdapter(adapterOrder);
                        adapterOrder.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }catch (NullPointerException e){
                        Log.e("Error", " generateAdapter NullPointerException ERROR => "+e.getMessage());
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        Log.e("Error", " generateAdapter Exception ERROR => "+e.getMessage());
                    }                       
                }
            });
```

the adapter is something like this:

```
public class orderItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order>{
    public ArrayList<Order> orders;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public orderItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> orders){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, orders);
        this.orders = orders;   

        Log.v("mfb", "orderItem "+this.orders.size());
    }

    public void add(int index, Order order){
        this.orders.add(index, order);
    }

    @Override        
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View vi=convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        if(convertView==null){  
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_user, null);
        }

        Order order = orders.get(position);
        if(order != null){
            TextView nombre = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.nombre); 
            TextView edadCumplir = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.edadCumplir);
            //TextView mes = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mes);
            TextView dia = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.dia);

            //Log.v("mfb", " order position => "+position);

            if(nombre != null){
                nombre.setText(orders.get(position).getNombre());
                //Log.v("mfb", "orderItemAdapter nombre =>" + nombre.getText());
            }

            if(edadCumplir != null){
                edadCumplir.setText("Turning " + orders.get(position).getCumpliendo());
            }

            /*if(mes != null){
                mes.setText(orders.get(position).getMes());
            }*/

            if(dia != null){
                dia.setText(orders.get(position).getDia());
            }
        }           
        return vi;
    }               
}
```